# what does the "L" in "L-function" stand for?

Tags: terminology, special-functions, l-functions

I haven't been able to find a reference that tells what word (if a word) the L is short for.

Comment: This was asked on MathOverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/21375/why-are-they-called-l-functions

Answer (score 1):

From [KConrad](https://mathoverflow.net/users/3272/kconrad) on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21375/why-are-they-called-l-functions):

> It is not known why Dirichlet denoted his functions with an $L$. 
>   Perhaps he chose $L$ for Legendre (I am not serious). The reason may
>   be alphabetical. Just before $L$-functions are introduced in his 1837
>   paper on primes in arithmetic progression (Math. Werke vol. 1,
>   313–342), there are certain functions $G$ and $H$, and the letters
>   $I, J$, and $K$ may not have seemed appropriate labels for a function.
>
> While $L(s,\chi)$ and $L(\chi,s)$ are common notations for the
>   $L$-function of a character $\chi$, neither decorated notation is due
>   to Dirichlet; he simply wrote different $L$-functions as $L_0, L_1, L_2,\dots$.